# Decrease Regex steps

Tags: c#, regex, performance

At the moment I'm trying to build a (C#-)Regex to rename variables in a C#-Sourcefile. It should avoid DllImports, and avoid renaming string contents, and avoid renaming variables containing the name to replace (e.g. not replacing "anotherTest" when "Test" is to replace). 
Well the Regex works, but It is really slow. RegexBuddy told me it takes 411 steps to debug this input (Yes I know it's totally dumb code, but it's for testing purposes):

> [DllImport("user32.dll")]   [return:...] public extern int test();
>
> "test "
>
> ""test
>
> testProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = (start + \"\" \"" + test + "\")");

As I'm new to Regex, I don't know where to improve it... I hope someone can help me...

Here's the (C#-)Regex itself:

```
(?<!\[DllImport\(.*\)\]\s*\r\n(|\[return\:.*\]\s*\r\n).*)(?((?<![\"\'][^+=]*))|(?![^+=]*[\"\']))(?<![\w_]+?)test(?![\w_]+?)
```

Comment: Can't you use the refactoring functions your IDE provides?

Comment: In this case, unfourtunately not.